# For loops, conditional statements, counting

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

'No such value.' repeats for every `i` that doesn't satisfy the condition. Last line is always 'No such dimension.'

I've tried playing around with continue and break and indents.

```
print('Which dimension would you like to search on?')
dimension = input().lower()

#check for dimension. if it exists, search value. else, print 'No such dimension.'

for i in range(1,100,1):
    if str(sheet.cell(row=1, column=i).value.lower()) == dimension:
        searchcolumn = i
        print('Which ' + dimension.lower() + ' would you like to search for?')
        value = input().lower()

#check for value. if it exists, print row and count. else, print 'No such value.'

        for i in range(1,100,1):
            if str(sheet.cell(row=i, column=searchcolumn).value.lower()) == value \
            or str(sheet.cell(row=i, column=searchcolumn).value) == value:
                    print('Row ' + str(i))

            else: print('No such value.')
        else: print('No such dimension.')
        break
```

Expected: Inputting an invalid dimension returns 'No such dimension.' Script ends. Valid dimension then asks what value to look for.  Inputting a valid value returns only 'Row #'. Invalid value returns 'No such value.' Script ends.

Actual: Valid dimension is ok. Invalid dimension returns "AttributeError nonetype...". Valid value returns "No such value" and "Row #" interspersed, and "No such dimension" at the end. Invalid value returns ("no such value")*100 and "No such dimension."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, an `else` clause on a `for` loop executes whenever the loop is exhausted without reaching a `break` statement. As your inner loop does not have a `break` statement, at the end of your loop the `else` will always be executed and hence the unwanted print. This is why you would want to unindent that `else` to the line of the outer `for`. This means, looping on all columns and if any matched to the dimension we will never `break` and `No such dimension` will be printed.

Then the same goes for the inner loop. If we find the value we `print` and `break`. If we covered all the rows and never met the value, we didn't `break` and so the `else` will be executed and `No such value` will be printed. To put it all in code will be more clear :)

```py
dimension = input('Which dimension would you like to search on?').lower()

for i in range(1,100,1):
    if str(sheet.cell(row=1, column=i).value.lower()) == dimension:
        ...
        for i in range(1,100,1):
            if str(sheet.cell(row=i, column=searchcolumn).value).lower() == value:
                print('Row ' + str(i))
                break

        else: print('No such value.')
        break
else: print('No such dimension.')
```

If you want to print all matching values in the column we will have to go around that, something like:

```py
for i in range(1,100,1):
    if str(sheet.cell(row=1, column=i).value.lower()) == dimension:
        ...
        found = False
        for i in range(1,100,1):
            if str(sheet.cell(row=i, column=searchcolumn).value).lower() == value:
                print('Row ' + str(i))
                found = True

        if not found: print('No such value.')
        break
else: print('No such dimension.')
```

Lastly, you could also count how much rows matched and then use that as the checker. i.e:

```py
...
        found = 0
        for i in range(1,100,1):
            if str(sheet.cell(row=i, column=searchcolumn).value).lower() == value:
                print('Row ' + str(i))
                found += 1

        if not found: print('No such value.')
        else: print(f"Found {found} values")
        break
...
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. However, I'd like to take it two steps further. If I'm understanding correctly, the break triggers on the first time the condition is met. How would you see every row a value is on? That is, break only at the end of the range and count how many times the condition has been met?

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand. I think I kind of foresaw what you are talking about and hence added the second code, maybe you missed it. If you are talking about doing a `counter` of how many values matched that's another thing but completely not a problem. Try to clarify @programmerdan